# send sms with sim900 using arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, sim900

```
 #include <Password.h> 
#include <Keypad.h> 
#include <Servo.h> 
#include "SIM900.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "sms.h"

Servo myservo; 
Password password = Password( "1234" ); //password to unlock box, can be changed
SMSGSM sms;
int numdata;
boolean started=false;
char smsbuffer[160];
char n[20];

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 

// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 9, 8, 7, 6 };// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = { 5, 4, 3, 2 };
int x=0;


// Create the Keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup()     //if i add sms(); function it workssss
{ 

   Serial.begin(9600); //Start a Serial COM

   Serial.println(F("ARDUINO SECURITY SYSTEM V1.0"));

   Serial.print(F("Checking GSM COM..."));

  if (gsm.begin(9600)) //Start the GSM COM
  {
    (sms.SendSMS("+XXXXX","Your Home Security system is powered up"));
    Serial.println(F("Good To GO!!"));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("Could not connect to GSM modem"));
  }

  Serial.write(254);
  Serial.write(0x01);
  delay(200); 
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);  //green light
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);  //red light
  myservo.attach(13); //servo on digital pin 9 //servo
  keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent);//add an event listener for this keypad

  }

void loop(){
  keypad.getKey();
  myservo.write(0);
  }
  //take care of some special events
  void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent eKey){
  switch (keypad.getState()){
  case PRESSED:

  Serial.print("Enter : ");
  Serial.println(eKey);
  delay(10);

  Serial.write(254);

  switch (eKey){
    case 'A': checkPassword(); delay(1); break;
    case 'C': checkPassword(); delay(1); break;
    case 'D': checkPassword(); delay(1); break;
    case 'B': password.reset(); delay(1); break;
    case '*': checkPassword(); break;
    case '#': password.reset(); break;

    default: password.append(eKey); delay(1);
  }
 }
}
void checkPassword(){

if (password.evaluate()){  //if password is right open box

    Serial.println("Accepted");
    Serial.write(254);delay(50);
    //Add code to run if it works
    myservo.write(5); //160deg

        digitalWrite(11, HIGH);//turn on
    delay(2000); //wait 5 seconds
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);// turn off   
}
else
{

    Serial.println("Denied"); //if passwords wrong keep box locked
    Serial.write(254);delay(10);
    x++;

    if(x==3)
    //add code to run if it did not work
   {
    myservo.write(0);
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 
    delay(500); 
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);  
  if (gsm.begin(9600)) 
  {
    (sms.SendSMS("+XXXXX","Your Home Security system is being bridged"));

    Serial.println("USER WARNED");
   }

}
}
}
;
}
```

In the picture the same code doesn't seem to work when I place the lines

```
if (gsm.begin(9600)) //Start the GSM COM
  {
    (sms.SendSMS("+8613668914901","Your Home Security system is being bridged"));
```

but this lines work great inside the void setup function.

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Inside the void setup the sketch works fine but when I also put the code in the function CheckPassword it doesn't send SMS.

I also tried to create a function let's say void SMS and call it in the checkPassword function but it doesn't solve the problem, btw the same function when called in the void setup works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to initialize the `gsm` only once, in the `setup` function.

In your code you attempt to initialize it again in the `checkPassword` method, and that is obviously not going to work.

Thus you should remove the line `gsm.begin(9600)` from the `checkPassword` function.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

In your scheme you reserve the **pins** *9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2* for the Keyboard. However, at the same time you reserve pins *2, 3* for your **GSM** module (see `GSM.cpp`):

```
 #define _GSM_TXPIN_ 2
 #define _GSM_RXPIN_ 3
```

Using the same pins for multiple purposes can often result (if not done properly) in undefined behaviour which in the best scenario means that your sketch isn't doing what it is supposed to do, and in the worst scenario it might damage your components.

You are already using pins *0, 1* for the **Serial** library, but according to your code the pins *10, 11, 13* should still be free if you want to relocate the existing pins to your components.

Notice also the following **warnings** inside the **GSM** library:

> [3]   My shield doesn't work. Why?
>
> Check this steps and then ask for support on the issues' page on google
>     code.
>
> 1)  SIM900 and SIM908 require about 1 A during the hardest tasks.
>         You should have an external power source that can provide about
>         1 A at 8-12 V
>
> 2)  If the SIM90X blinks (1 Hz) for some seconds and then turn off,
>         probably it's a communication's problem. Check the switch/jumpers
>         for Serial communication.
>
> 3)  Arduino Uno has 2 KB of RAM. Library takes about 80% (we are working
>         to reduce it), if you use more than 20% left, Arduino can restart
>         or print on serial strange strings.
>
> 4)  Check the jumper of communication, power source (battery or externel) and charge.

Comment: I removed the gsm.begin(9600) from the checkPassword function, the sketch runs good but still no message sent, it seems to execute the line (sms.SendSMS("+xxxxx","xxxxx") and prints the next line "User Warned", but it doesn't actually send the message! How can i solve it now! appreciate your help

Comment: If you can provide me with a link to the library you are using, which I could not find, then I might be able to help you @drexxx

Comment: can i mail it to you?

Comment: i just mailed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @drexxx I just updated my answer. Please update your sketch and let me know if it works, or further checks are needed. In case it doesn't work, update the question with the newest version of your code/problem.

Comment: I changed the pins 2,3 in the keyboard function to 10,13; and keep the pins 2,3 only for gsm library and the code is working just fine, appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My project also include lcd16x02 display, some sensors relays, can you suggest some nice way to avoid the pins problems because i would always need to use the same pins for other functions, thanks a lot

Comment: In general, the solution is to use a *multiplexer*, when it is possible. Or @drexxx you can buy a larger board, like the Arduino Mega. In your case, I think you should try to accomodate the Keypad in a circuit that uses only 1 pin, for example following these instructions http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/OneWireKeyPad . If you google, there exists LCD devices that use only 2 pins too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, feel much better the project was killing me, now getting t like Arduino.